# Calculate the total occurence of specific elements in an array of lists

Tags: python, pandas

I am getting the below array list as an output of my for loop. How can I calculate the total number of true and false (separate) coming in each list.

```
[array(['false', 'false', 'false', 'true', 'true', 'true', 'false', 'true',
       'false', 'true', 'false', 'false'], dtype='|S5')]
[array(['false', 'false', 'false', 'true', 'true', 'true', 'false', 'true',
       'false', 'true', 'false', 'false'], dtype='|S5')
```

The code which generate this output is:

```
for df in df_elements:
        cutoff_list_neg.append(np.where((df['score'])>=0, 'true', 'false'))
        print cutoff_list_neg
```

df_elements is a list of dataframes:

```
[                          seq  score    status
 2911  TCATCCCGATTTTGATGCATCTA  -2.96  negative
 3477                ATGGCACTG  -3.60  negative
 178                 TTAGAAAGC  -3.78  negative
 4667  CTAATGATGATGCTCTTCAGTAC   2.01  negative
 1401  ACTGACTTCTTTAAATGAAGAGT   1.67  negative
 351   ATCTGCTCTTCGTGTTGAAGAAG   4.32  negative
 3678  AAGGATCGCTATGGCTCCTGGAT  -5.39  negative
 2294  ATTATCTTTAACTGATGAAGAGC   0.15  negative
 5378  TCATCTCTCTGAAAAACAAGATA  -1.88  negative
 4290  AACCTGCAATCCGGAACCAGATC   2.72  negative
 3353                CCGATGGGC  -1.97  negative
 4124  CGGACATTGCCGAGTCCCAGGTC  -2.31  negative,
                           seq  score    status
 2787                AAGGTTGGC   6.10  negative
 5378  TCATCTCTCTGAAAAACAAGATA  -1.88  negative
 3928                AGCGAAACG  -7.32  negative
 3678  AAGGATCGCTATGGCTCCTGGAT  -5.39  negative
 1607  AGGCACAACTTATGTAACAGATA   2.32  negative
 4685  TGCTCTTCAGTACGTTGAAGAAT  -2.35  negative
 1652  TGGCTTCGATTTTGTTATCGATG  -0.22  negative
 3477                ATGGCACTG  -3.60  negative
 275   TCTGTTGGGTTTTCATACAGCTA   7.11  negative
 3769  CAGGTGAGCTGTCGCGGCAGCTG   0.98  negative
 663   TATTAAGTATTCTCTAGCAGACC   3.61  negative
 1855                TTCGGATGC  -6.88  negative
```

```
Desired output is:
item   True    False
df1    5       7
df2    5       7
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you need list comprehension with [`Series.value_counts`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html):

```
cutoff_list_neg = [(df['score']>=0).value_counts() for df in df_elements]
```

Loop version:

```
cutoff_list_neg = []
for df in df_elements:
    val = (df['score']>=0).value_counts()
    cutoff_list_neg.apprnd(val)
```

And then use [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) with transpose and rename index names:

```
df = (pd.concat(cutoff_list_neg, axis=1, ignore_index=True)
        .T
        .rename(lambda x: 'df{}'.format(x + 1)))
print (df)
     False  True 
df1      7      5
df2      7      5
```

Comment: The concat command is giving me this error (at the last ' ):     SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: @ranusharma - Can you check now?

Comment: It is working now. However, the output format is different in my case. I am getting this on printing df.  [False    7
True     5
Name: score, dtype: int64, False    7
True     5

Comment: I checked. The code below loop alternative is giving me the output you provided. The loop alternative didn't.

Comment: Can I pass additional for loop after one for loop (df in df_elements).... ?                        cut_off = range(0, 10)
Like this:
cutoff_list_neg = [((df['score']>=co).value_counts() for df in df_elements) for co in cut_off]
If needed, I can edit the question above..

Comment: @ranusharma - yes, but simplier in loop version it is, I will edit answer